# Wifi doesn't work in Ubuntu 15.10 - Realtek RTL8723BE/RTL8188EE 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Drivers

Tags: wireless, 15.10, hp, realtek-wireless

My laptop is a HP Notebook - 15-ac173tx having Realtek RTL8723BE/RTL8188EE 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Drivers.

I can not work with my wifi properly as it drops once in a while, and also I can't log into a wifi network if the wifi router is in another room even if I connect to a wifi network really close to my lap the signal strength of the wifi is really low.

Please help me to fix this issue asap.

Comment: Does `modinfo -p rtl8723be` show ant_sel as an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914048/realtek-rtl8723be-weak-wifi-signal-and-disconnects) question, if you have any trouble with getting it fixed make sure you check the ReadMe file on github