# Realtek RTL8723BE weak wifi signal and disconnects

Tags: drivers, wireless, 17.04, rtl8723be

**Model:** **HP 15-af030ur** inside **Realtek RTL8723B**
***ware:** 2 years have problems under Linux Ubuntu 14.04LTS -> 16.04LTS -> 17.04 Gnome 3.24 wayland
**Problem:** weak wifi signal problem in ubuntu based linux distributions, but  work well with windows
try all solutions, nothing help

Comment: Which "all" solutions did you try? It is quite obvious that you did not try any.

Comment: Wow !!! I remember your nickname. A year and a half ago I used all your advice that I could find. Thanks for the help!
Unfortunately nothing helped on HP 15-af030ur

Answer (score 5):

And finally I found a solution that works for me (checked on 2 laptops of same model with different versions of Ubuntu: 16.04LTS and 17.04)

1. Open Terminal, and enter:

   ```
   iwconfig
   ```

   And note down the **wl* number**.
2. [Download the new driver **rock.new_btcoex** from Github](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/tree/rock.new_btcoex) and `unzip` it to Desktop folder.
3. In Terminal, now run these commands:

   ```
   cd Desktop/rtlwifi_new-rock.new_btcoex
   make
   sudo make install` type your ubuntu password
   sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
   sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=2
   sudo ip link set wl* up` use your **wl* number**
   sudo iw dev wl* scan` same
   ```

To make the settings permanent, use this command:

```
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/50-rtl8723be.conf
```

**Note:** After your OS (Kernel) update, you need to apply these settings again to get a strong signal.

Comment: There is no need to install anything from git for new Ubuntu versions. `ant_sel` has been committed to the kernel a while ago.

Comment: Need only change option to `ant_sel=2` ?

Comment: Correct. To `1` or `2`.