# Ubuntu realtek wifi problem

Tags: 16.04, realtek, rtl8723be

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and it has rtl8723be driver and does not shows wifi. 
I have tried all the methods stated in these [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/628641/rtl8723be-poor-and-unstable-wireless-in-ubuntu-from-14-04-to-15-04?newreg=8b1a7b49b3134cc5804d5d00a8fd8c03), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914048/realtek-rtl8723be-weak-wifi-signal-and-disconnects) . Also installled new drivers from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git. Any leads would be helpful.

`output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    DeviceName: Sanji2 
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:81c1]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: updated @Pilot6

Comment: It looks OK. What is the kernel `uname -a`? And what do you mean by "does not shows wifi"?

Comment: Except of the  sources of my answer I just found this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/883673/rtl8723be-wifi-incredibly-weak... It is somehow the same but try my answer first because all steps needed.

Answer (score 0):

**First attempt:**

Try the commands with your installed version:

```
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
sudo modprobe -rf rtl8723be
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be
```

Check if you can find wifi.

If you do... just restart and it is ready.

Before go to the second attempt, try with option `ant_sel=2` (and again all three commands)

**Second attempt:**

Go to the source folder of the package installed and uninstall it by running the command

```
sudo make uninstall
```

Then run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms
```

(I think it is the same package you already installed but it works for my 16.04 and it will accept updates too)

Again all the commands of the first attempt:

```
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
sudo modprobe -rf rtl8723be
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be
```

You should find wifi after the last command.

If not try `ant_sel=2` on above options and give all the (3) commands

If it is better:

Restart and ready.

Sources (combination):

https://kharisecario.wordpress.com/2017/03/16/installing-realtek-rtl8723be-wifi-driver-for-debian/

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2364060&highlight=rtl8723be

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2363051&highlight=rtl8723be