# Realtek RTL8723BE/RTL8188EE 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Drivers

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

I have tried the steps as detailed in the answer of this AskUbuntu question: ["Wifi doesn't work in Ubuntu 15.10 - Realtek RTL8723BE/RTL8188EE 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Driver"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/756880/wifi-doesnt-work-in-ubuntu-15-10-realtek-rtl8723be-rtl8188ee-802-11b-g-n-wire),
but I have got this error:

```
error: #error "This branch is abandoned. Please do not use"
```

Can anyone provide a fix? I downloaded the driver called "Realtek RTL8723BE/RTL8188EE 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Drivers" and installed it with `ndisgtk`, but the Wi-Fi doesn't work. I have also tried changing the `ant_sel=` to `1`, but to no avail.

Comment: In order to get the driver in the answer to work, you will probably need to purge ndisrwapper.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the latest official drivers for this card and the install instructions at [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: I read that I should install from the extended branch, which I did and finally got WiFi; but with incredibly horrible range (approx. 2.5m before disconnection). The creator of the repository said to update the Kernel to 4.15.3 and use the driver pre-installed in that version and specifically not to use the repo's drivers. I updated but still do not have wireless connection.

Comment: Have you tried changing which antenna rtlwifi_new is using?

    modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=2

Comment: Yeah, I tried that.