# Wifi adapter not found in Ubuntu 18.04, none of the approaches so far resolves isse

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, wireless, realtek-wireless

The last time I booted my computer I could no longer access the wifi adapter, after some looking around I realized that Ubuntu was not finding any Wifi adapter in the system, it was working fine until I booted my system I'm guessing it was because of one of the internal updates which I get every day. From other posts, I've seen people asking for output of

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

Which is:

`03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8197]
    Kernel modules: rtl8188ee`

I have tried a lot of approaches mentioned on various platforms including the questions answered for an almost a duplicate question on askubuntu and none of the approaches solves my problem that is why I needed to ask a new question. There isn't any problem in the Wifi adapter physically because I have Ubuntu dual booted on my desktop and it works fine in Windows. Also, I have connected the computer with an ethernet cable from the wifi router and it works fine as well.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about the 'approaches' you've tried so far? For example, which question on AU did you follow to no success? Try plugging in the ethernet cable while the wifi adapter is plugged in, and running the commands listed in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1153485/431864)

Comment: Does wireless work after `sudo modprobe -v rtl8188ee` or does it give an error?

Comment: `sudo modprobe -v rtl8188ee` gives the following error. 

`insmod /lib/modules/4.15.0-54-generic/updates/dkms/rtlwifi.ko 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8188ee': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)`

And this is the answer I followed on AU. [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047245/wifi-adapter-not-found-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: This problem was resolved once I ran the command `sudo apt upgrade` there were a lot of upgrades pending worth over 300Mbs which are now done.

Comment: This steps solved same issue for me.Hope you too could be successful.
[Please follow the link for detail method](https://www.techyo.ga/2019/08/wifi-driver-not-installed-on-hp-laptop.html)