# Ubuntu 18.04.2 rtl8188ee will not connect to any wifi

Tags: networking, drivers

I am working with a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04.2. When looking at available wifi, everything has an extremely weak signal even when right next to the router. things i have tried include "sudo modprobe -r rtl8188ee" followed by sudo rtl8188ee ant_set=1". Also repeated that command with "2" I have also done everything in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069513/about-rtl8188ee-driver-on-ubuntu-18-04) link. I can not get the wireless card to connect to anything, even though my wifi shows up with an extremely weak signal.

Comment: ensure rtl8188ee is the right module for your hardware with `sudo lshw -C network`

Comment: That's how I determined that my card was a rtl8188ee.

Comment: Is `ant_sel` a valid driver parameter for rtl8188ee? Find out: `modinfo rtl8188ee` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: It is in fact a valid parameter.