# Ubuntu 20.04 - Wifi not working

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04, realtek-wireless, tp-link

I'm new on Ubuntu, I'm trying it for my very first time and also facing some issues on it.

I noticed that my WiFi adapter is not working properly on Ubuntu. Simply, it doesn't show any WiFi network.

What is really crazy is that, if I 'try' Ubuntu from the installation drive, WiFi works excellent.

The device is Tp Link tl-wn781nd and looks like it has a realtek chipset under name RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter (information from command `sudo lshw -class network`)

I'm adding some information for your understanding:

```
iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp7s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp6s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

```
sudo lshw -class network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: wlp6s0
       version: 01
       serial: d0:37:45:71:63:e5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8188ee driverversion=5.8.0-40-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:62 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fcc00000-fcc03fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 0c
       serial: b4:2e:99:9c:c8:83
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.8.0-40-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=192.168.0.171 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:37 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fcb00000-fcb00fff memory:f0300000-f0303fff
```

Any clue on what could be the route cause of this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Run `rfkill` in a terminal. It should show your WiFi adapter as unblocked. This won't fix anything, but if it might give you another piece of the puzzle.

Comment: Hi Joe, first of all, thanks for answering this topic.
I've tried what you suggest and I see that my adapter is shown as 'unblocked'

ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
 1 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked

Any clue?

Comment: See if any of these help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170936/how-to-get-realtek-semiconductor-co-ltd-rtl8188ee-wireless-network-adapter-r https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069513/about-rtl8188ee-driver-on-ubuntu-18-04 Search the web for linux wireless RTL8188EE . It looks like you might need a special kernel module for it.

Comment: On my notebook, the WiFi somehow died. I worked on it forever and finally gave up and bought a USB WiFi adapter. If worst comes to worst and you need to go that route, the Panda PAU06 and PAU09 work. Wireless chipsets are worse than video cards for proprietary nonsense so most won't work with Linux.