# Weak wifi signal rtl8723be

Tags: drivers, wireless, 18.04, rtl8723be

I have a HP Pavilion Laptop. The details of which, obtained by running the command `lshw`, are below:

```
product: HP Pavilion Notebook (N1J39EA#A2N)
    vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    version: Type1ProductConfigId
    serial: 5CD5291DWT
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.8 dmi-2.8 smp vsyscall32
```

I switched from windows to Ubuntu 18.04 very recently. Initially I did face wifi weak signal issue. However, I fixed the issue by using the following commands:

```
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=2
sudo ip link set wlo1 up
sudo iw dev wlo1 scan
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

Everything was working perfectly and then 2 days ago I updated my system and thereby the kernel got updated which in turn brought back wifi issue.

I tried to fix wifi issue by using the same old method but failed to do so.
I also tried the following:

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf <<< "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1"
```

which also couldn't solve the issue. Then I went on to try the following:

```
sudo -i
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
exit
reboot
```

the same result with same problem.
output of the command

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
```

is as follows:

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:804c]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 0a)
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

References:

[Weak Signal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883673/realtek-rtl8723be-wi-fi-incredibly-weak)

[inconsistent connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/756748/inconsistent-connection-and-super-slow-speed-with-rtl8723be)

[weak signal and disconnection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914048/realtek-rtl8723be-weak-wifi-signal-and-disconnects)

Comment: This worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/914048/realtek-rtl8723be-weak-wifi-signal-and-disconnects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wifi networks not found ubuntu 18.04 with rtl8723be.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069153/wifi-networks-not-found-ubuntu-18-04-with-rtl8723be) It seems kernel v4.15.0-33 has a bug.

Comment: Alternatively, try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068826/wifi-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts

Comment: [link] https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068826/wi-fi-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts-rtl8723be this worked for me